# Search multiple lists of checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want to have several lists of checkboxes and make each of them searchable.** Like the site below which can be seen on the left sidebar.

https://www.trendyol.com/sr?lc=108254%2C105647%2C104591&mid=137544&os=1&pi=3

I searched for my question and the following question was very similar to my question. But the answer they gave was **only** for a single list of checkboxes, **while I have several lists on one page.**

How can I extend this answer to work for multiple lists, each with its own search?

[live search in input with checkbox filter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353526/live-search-in-input-with-checkbox-filter-value)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [live search in input with checkbox filter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353526/live-search-in-input-with-checkbox-filter-value)

Comment: The linked question already answers your question. All you have to do is to include multiple containers with your `querySelectorAll()` function and not just one.

Comment: @cloned Thank you very much, I am very beginner and can easily solve it correctly. Will you show me the solution?